# Django Elastic Beanstalk App - Cannot Set Secure Listener Port to 443: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a pretty new developer and deployed my first Django app via Elastic Beanstalk. I want to serve https requests and have configured my SSL certificate and have my load balancer set up correctly. When I go into EB > Configuration > Secure listener port and set it to 443 I'm getting the error upon saving:

```
LoadBalancerHTTPSPort: You have specified both the @deprecated(:default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort) 
    option as well as one in the new aws:elb:listener:443 namespace. 
The :default.aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort option will be ignored.
```

Not sure what I'm missing because I'm still not able to serve https requests

Comment: Same here. But I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk app. However, I was able to get around it by updating the Listener/Certificate settings via the AWS EC2 console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/), via the Load Balancers section (under LOAD BALANCING).

I was updating the certificate for a staging version of a cloned environment. This was the only way I could assign a different certificate to the staging environment.

See more at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html